# Can't Create Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm brand new to BigQuery/SQL and also to stack overflow. I'm following the Google Data Analytics Course and have been following their step by step instructions on basic SQL processes.

For some reason, I absolutely cannot create a table in BigQuery. I've tried all kinds of settings, making new projects and datasets, and uploading different files. I keep getting an 'Unexpected Error: Tracking number c3841839608749161" with a different long number every time.

Maybe its because I'm using the sandbox feature instead of the free trial? Whatever it is, getting help for this issue has been very obtuse and frustrating. I feel like this should be an incredibly basic/obvious process and I'm missing something despite the step by step instructions. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are trying to load a table to an existing dataset.

Steps:

Create a new project first. Then you go to your SQL Workspace and on the left you can see your first project.

Click on it and you will see your dataset INFO. On top of it there is a button "create table".

In the first drop - down menu "Source" choose the cvs file you want to upload. Choose dataset and table name and set up your schema.

This should work :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KXUr.png)

PS: In the beginning it can be a little difficult, especially when there's not enough information out there to help you with seemingly easy things, but not so straightforward for a beginner, but please don't give up!:)

Answer (score 0):

When I follow the step of Following

***Create a new project first. Then you go to your SQL Workspace and on the left you can see your first project.***

It does not open the working space. Any suggestions to fix this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrLMn.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).